# Unable to read internal storage file with html <a> on Webview

Tags: android

I am currently having problems referenceing a a file created into internal storage from my web view. the same code can reference similar file through href from a web address but when I decided to save the same file into internal storage I get Web Page at /data/data/packageName/files/fileName.html might be temporarily down.... any help would be appreciated

The line below resulted in an error when clicked on Webview:
`<a href='/data/data/packageName/files/fileName.html'>`
in fact when I tried with file:// the click was completely ignored as in `<a href='/data/data/packageName/files/fileName.html'>`

Meanwhile the same line works with `<a href="http://www.someweb.co.uk/fileName.html'>` is there any known workaround?

Comment: What did you use as full URL? For me `file:///data/data/packageName/...` (three slashes in the beginning) works

Comment: Can you show the sample that worked. On my side here href='http://www.example.com' worked but href='file:///data/data/package/files/filename' did not work.

Comment: It doesn't work, are there any updates @DeeTee ?